# AngularJS ng-repeat não está pegando valores

Tags: angularjs

Estou retornando um json com esse código:

```
$scope.movies = angular.toJson(results, true);
```

and getting this json: http://pastebin.com/87tJm8XE

E tentando pegar os dados com esse:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{movie.title}}
</ion-item>
```

mas eu estava tendo um erro:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.

então eu tentei isso:

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="movie in movies track by $index">
     {{movie.title}}
 </ion-item>
```

mas agora não consigo ter os valores. {{movie.title}} retorna vazio.

Comment: Parece que você perguntou no site errado... aqui é o SO em **português**!

Comment: Nossa, não tinha visto, desculpe, já editei

Answer (score 2):

Não entendo porque está transformando o objeto em um string JSON. Não me parece apropriado.

#### Sugestão 1:

```
$scope.movies = results.data.results;
```

E use seu HTML original:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{movie.title}}
</ion-item>
```

---

#### Sugestão 2:

```
$scope.movies = results;
```

E no HTML:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="data.results in movies">
    {{movie.title}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.usei a prieira opção e funcionou.
Eu peguei um exemplo pronto e ele transforma o objeto em string json, não sabia o que era isso na verdade.